# How Do I Remove All Forward Slashes Between XML Tags While Leaving the Text?

Tags: regex, xml, awk, sed, notepad++

I have some VERY large XML files. I need to remove all forward slashes between the opening and closing XML tags. The foward slashes can be replaced with spaces. I need to do this without removing the forward slashes from the closing HTML tags. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This:

```
<XML>
<REDACTED27> CT LSPINE W/O CONT XR29 </REDACTED27>
<sampletag>str1/str2/str3</sampletag>
</XML>
```

Becomes This:

```
<XML>
<REDACTED27> CT LSPINE W O CONT XR29 </REDACTED27>
<sampletag>str1 str2 str3</sampletag>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lacking an xml aware tool, this works for simple structures

```
$ sed -r 's_([^<])/([^>])_\1 \2_g' xml

<XML>
<REDACTED27> CT LSPINE W O CONT XR29 </REDACTED27>
<sampletag>str1 str2 str3</sampletag>
</XML>
<test/>
```

Comment: @jjones150 You are not really lacking an XML-aware tool. Don't use the incorrect solution for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Use a XML aware tool that parses the actual XML. For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can just write

```
open file.xml ;
for //text() set . xsh:subst(., '/', ' ', 'g') ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Nice, that's quite a bit more convenient than XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

It's best when you don't do that with sed, awk or any other text editing utility.

Use an XML editing utility, for example XSLT.

The following transformation leaves the input untouched (except from indenting it nicely, but you can disable that) and just modifies text nodes (i.e. the stuff *"between the opening and closing XML tags"*):

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '/', ' ')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Save as e.g. `removeslashes.xsl` and use [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) on the command line.

```
xsltproc -o outputfile.xml removeslashes.xsl inputfile.xml
```

Comment: "Very very large" as in "starting at a GB of XML". Then, yes, it might not work at some point. But that's hardly ever a use-case (quite probably not here) and it applies to any DOM-based processing (i.e. the `xsh` approach also). XSLT 3.0 with streaming or SAX would be the right tools in such a case.

Comment: @Tomalak: In `xsh`, you can use the SAX-like `stream` command.

Answer (score 1):

You should install `xmlstarlet`, then basically:

```
xmlstarlet pyx source.xml | perl -pe 'm/^-/ && s/\// /g' | xmlstarlet p2x > target.xml
```

In pyx, lines starting with `-' denote text nodes, therefore you replace slashes in them and assemble xml back without touching anything else.

Comment: Nice as well! But... does this start one new perl instance per text node? :o

Comment: @Tomalak no, all three processes should be in pipe mode, started only once and consuming virtually no RAM.

Comment: Would `xmlstarlet pyx source.xml | tr / ' ' | xmlstarlet p2x > target.xml` work?

Comment: No, because you will end up replacing slashes not just in text nodes but everywhere. You need that m/^-/ step.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. This should be voted higher, I think it's the best answer in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

As you included `notepad++` tag, I suggest a replace all (`Ctrl+H`) with this `regex` in the "Find what" (and a space in "Replace with")

```
(?<!<)/(?!>)
```

The negative lookbehind `(?<!<)` makes sure that no character `<` comes before the `/` and the negative lookahead `(?!>)` makes sure that there's not a `>` afterwards. Here I assume that no `</` or `/>` appear outside tags to process faster for your "VERY large XML files".